# Facebook open graph layout when actions and objects are not one to one

Tags: facebook, configuration, facebook-opengraph

I am building out open graph objects and actions for use with an application I am developing and would like to know if it is possible to have two different attachment layouts when a single action is connected to two different objects.

For example: I have an action "*Earn*" and two connected objects *Points* and *AnObject*, for the *points* object I would like the attachment preview to be "Number", however for the *AnObject* object I would like the attachment priview to be "Item". Is something like this possible? Or do I have to use the same attachment priview on both objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no. We want consistency within the same action. If they are different actions, then just make two actions. If they are the same, they should have consistent rendering.

Comment: Agreed, just create a new action/object pairing.

Comment: Thanks. It's the same action just taken against two different objects. You can "earn" both objects but the objects themselves are different. Since I can't create another "Earn" action to associate with the second object because it already exists, I will just come up with a different action name.